# dotnet pack in azure devops is not including the pdb file for one of my projects

Tags: azure-devops

I have a solution with about 70-ish projects, and I'm making the transition from building NuGet packages locally to building them via the pipeline in Azure DevOps, and there are things I just don't understand.

In today's episode, it's why most of my projects are building NuGet packages via dotnet pack in the Azure DevOps pipeline, but one of the projects isn't. It doesn't look much different from the others. It's small, with two classes and their interfaces, and a reference to another project within the solution...and that's about it. My oddball project is failing to generate a `.pdb` file, but the other projects in the same solution are generating theirs just fine.

Does the log file explain why it didn't build the `.pdb` file in the first place? As far as I can tell, the first mention I get is that the whole process fails because it can't find a non-existent `.pdb` file that it expects to have.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack#description), if `GeneratePackageOnBuild`<note 1> is set (in my case, in the `Directory.build.props`), then the pack target will fail to build, hence no `.pdb` file. This is to prevent a cyclic dependency.

The problem is that there is no error reporting about this situation whatsoever. It just silently fails to build the project without telling you why and then complains that there is no `.pdb` file because it didn't build in the first place.

<note 1> `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` = set
`<GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` = unset